# Local notification trigger continuously for one minute in android device

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am working with local notifications in ionic 2 app using the plugin -

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
npm install @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

The notification is working perfectly great in ios device but for android is shows unexpected behaviour.

**Excepted behaviour -**
Repeat the notification on same day at set time.

**Current behaviour-**
The notification is coming continuously for one minute.

My requirement is to repeat the local notification on particular day of every week with time set by user.The notification should also repeat on same day and time set by user.

Here is my code snippet-

```
makeLocalNotificationOn(mainDayNotifyObj, index) {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let currentDay = currentDate.getDay(); // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.

    let indexOfDay;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.remainderDaysArray.length; i++) {
        if (mainDayNotifyObj.dayName == this.remainderDaysArray[i]) {
            indexOfDay = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    let setTime = mainDayNotifyObj.time.split(":");
    let hours = parseInt(setTime[0]);
    let minutes = parseInt(setTime[1]);


    let firstNotificationTime = new Date();
    let dayDifference = indexOfDay - currentDay;

    if (dayDifference < 0) {
        dayDifference = dayDifference + 7; // for cases where the day is in the following week
    }

    firstNotificationTime.setHours(firstNotificationTime.getHours() + (24 * (dayDifference)));
    firstNotificationTime.setHours(hours);
    firstNotificationTime.setMinutes(minutes);

    let weekDay = firstNotificationTime.getDay();

       let remainderObj = {
            id: index,
            title: 'Hello',
            text: 'Its time',
            foreground: true,
            trigger: {every: {weekday: weekDay, hour: hours, minute: minutes},firstAt: firstNotificationTime}
        };

    this.notificationArray.push(remainderObj);

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.localNotifications.schedule(this.notificationArray);

    });

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Any one find the solution?
I am still stuck in this issue.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1533#issuecomment-514521588

If anyone still finds this post, the bug still exists **BUT** luckly it was fixed and commited by the original author tho he didn't create a new release, basically you have to remove the plugin and intall the head master of the repo instead, just follow the steps in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I did was modifying the MatchTrigger.java to compare seconds as well, so it only trigger for the second 00

So search for

```
if (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
            switch (unit) {
                case MINUTE:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                    break;
                case HOUR:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
                    break;
                case DAY:
                case WEEK:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                    break;
                case MONTH:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    break;
                case YEAR:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and replace the closing **}** for

```java
} else
        if (cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) < now.get(Calendar.SECOND)) {
            switch (unit) {
                case MINUTE:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                    break;
                case HOUR:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
                    break;
                case DAY:
                case WEEK:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                    break;
                case MONTH:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    break;
                case YEAR:
                    addToDate(cal, now, Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@valencianok  Thanks for your reply.I really appreciate that.

I solved my issue by modifying the trigger object values.

The remainder Object that I used to trigger the notification has some changes.

here is the code snippet-

```
remainderObj = {
            id: index,
            title: 'Hello',
            text: 'Its time',
            foreground: true,
            trigger{every{weekday:weekDay,hour:hours,minute:minutes},firstAt: firstNotificationTime,count:1}
        }
```

The **count** attribute did its work, the count = 1 trigger the notification only one time in android device.